# keep multiple select dropdown values after postback using ajax, jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Binding dropdown list using ajax and web method on button click postback occurs and values of dropdown gets reset.
already tried=I am storing values in the hidden field and assigning back to the dropdown by calling function on  button click but my hidden field is loosing values on postback

Tried jquery function:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClientProjectStatus"   runat="server" CssClass="form-control " multiple="multiple" onchange="SelectedValue(this)" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="width: 50px">

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control " multiple="multiple"  onchange="SelectedValue(this)" ClientIDMode="Static"  Style="width: 50px">

<script>
        function SelectedValue(dropdown) {
            $("#hdf" + dropdown.id.substr(3)).val($("#" + dropdown.id).val())
}
</script>
//Calling ConformationBox when the page is doing postback (asp.net)
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(DropDownChange);
  function DropDownChange() {
  $('#ddlClient').on('change', function (e) {
                dropdownBind('Client', 'getResourceTypeAccordingtoClient', 'StatusId', 'Status', 'ClientProjectStatus');               
            });
}

  <script>
        function dropdownBind(ActualFieldName, TableName, ValueField, DataField, AffectFieldName) {

            document.getElementById("hdf" + ActualFieldName).value = $('#ddl' + ActualFieldName).val();
          
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0] + '/ControlName',
                data: "{'sValue':'" + value + "','sField':'" + ActualFieldName + "','sProjectId':'" + $('#ddlProjectName').val() + "','aField':'" + AffectFieldName + "','sClients':'" + $('#ddlClient').val() + "','sClientProjectId':'" + $('#ddlClientProjectName').val() + "'}",
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {

                    // Now find the Table from response and loop through each item (row).
                    $('#ddl' + AffectFieldName + ' option').remove();
                    $(response.d).find('' + TableName + '').each(function () {
                        // Get the OptionValue and OptionText Column values.
                        var OptionValue = $(this).find(ValueField).text();
                        var OptionText = $(this).find(DataField).text();

                        // Create an Option for DropDownList.
                        var option = $("<option>" + OptionText + "</option>");
                       
                        option.attr("value", OptionValue);
                        
                        $('#ddl' + AffectFieldName).append(option);

                    });
                  
                    var ClientReportFields = AffectFieldName.slice(0, 6);
                    if (ClientReportFields == 'Client') {
                        $('#ddl' + AffectFieldName).multipleSelect('refresh', { placeholder: '--Select--' });
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    //$(".loader").css("display", "none");
                   
                }
            });
        }

  <script>
        function AssignvaluesOnPostback() {
            alert(document.getElementById("hdfClientProjectStatus").value);
            var value = document.getElementById("hdfClientProjectStatus").value;
           
            $.each(value.split(","), function (i, e) {
                $("#ddlClientProjectStatus option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
                $('#ddlClientProjectStatus').multipleSelect('refresh', { placeholder: '--Select --' });
             
            });
        }
        </script>

//on button click calling javascript function
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "Javascript", "AssignvaluesOnPostback(); ", true);
```

Comment: Is your hidden field an ASP.NET web control? EnableViewState option can help. Or read its value on server side and reassign it manually when sending page to client

Comment: not able to check the items of dropdown list from code behind using method 
ddlClientProjectSatus.Items[1].Selected=true; and also tried
ddlClientProjectSatus.Items.FindByText("In Progress").Selected=true;
tried hiddenfield EnableViewState option but it's not working

Comment: You can find selected value of ddlClientProjectStatus by checking the Request property on the server side: Request[ddlClientProjectStatus.ClientID]

Comment: thank you Evgeny Gorb it's working now I tried binding it from code behind